# tikz pgfkeys error for isosceles triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just got this message compile with pdflatex:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/isosceles triangle' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I'm using fedora with texlive. What package am I missing?

Comment: Did you forget \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}?

Comment: \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}

Comment: (Ignore previous comment.) ... Thanks. It's working now. Funny it does not require that for an earlier version. (I just upgraded.) Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe they thought that was too easy ;)? Or maybe they split functionality out as a library because they greatly expanded the range of shapes covered or plan to do so. (Really no idea.)

Comment: This is slightly OT but I don't want to post another question. What is the standard way of figuring out what library is missing?

Comment: I don't know. What I did was open the tikz manual and the searched for the key isosceles using my pdf viewer's find command. I'm not sure that's a standard method, though. I just generally find it works for me. Maybe somebody else can suggest something better? (But you might want to ask a new question to draw attention to it in that case.) I'd be interested in whether there's a better way.

Comment: @user2926204 This is actually worth to be asked as a new own question! (But I did not check, whether it was already asked before.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
```

to your preamble in order to access this aspect of tikz's functionality. See page 420 of the user manual.

I'm only adding this example from the manual to make this answer slightly longer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [isosceles triangle, fill=gray!25, minimum width=1.5cm] (t) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: isosceles triangle based on tikz manual example]

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,5.2)
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Recommended

For those who dislike rounding, you might regard the following improvement not only be useful but also beautiful.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,\eval{6*sin(pi/3)})
\pspolygon(6,0)(6;60)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But I think, `\eval` in

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

should be provided out of the box to avoid declaring the code above repeatitively every time I need `\eval` as it wastes more keystrokes.